# Inherit class properties from another file in scss

Tags: html, angular, sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to inherit the class properties of class `AClass` from a file named `A.scss` into another file `B.scss` and overwrite some of its properties as per my requirement

Suppose A.scss has,

```
.AClass{
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

and i want to inherit the `.AClass`of the `A.scss` file and change it to something else. Then how do i inherit the property

Comment: Use `@extend` (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend)

Comment: But suppose these files are in different folders
can you please show me how, I am getting it hard to inherit from scss, it would be of great help

Comment: `@import` the file you want to inherit and the use `@extend .AClass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To inherit styles from class, you should use [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) keyword. If the parent class is defined in another file, this file has to be first imported with [`@import`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) directive:

```
// A.scss
.A {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```
// B.scss
@import 'A';

.B {
  @extend .A;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

This compiles to the following CSS:

```css
.A, .B {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.B {
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

You can try it online [here](https://sass.js.org/).